# FileNotFoundException when accessing a file from JSP but works if accessed from plain java application

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am trying to access a properties file from java and it works file when I run it as a stand-alone java application. But, when I call the method accessing the file from a jsp page running on a tomcat server, I get a FileNotFoundException.

I think that when the files are deployed into a server, their path changes, and thats why the exception occurs from a web-app but not directly in java. Below is the project explorer view of my project.

[image]

I am accessing the nWMS properties file from the LabelRequestMessages class in java. Below is the code with which I access the file in java.

```
in = new FileInputStream("resources-dev/com/infosys/gidl2/shiplabel/mybatis/config/"
                            + propsDB); //propsDB has the file name
            props.load(in);
```

Could someone please tell me how to provide the path so that the file is accessible when deployed in a tomcat server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get resources inside your `.war` application please consider using that

```
private static final String ENDINGS_FILE_NAME = "com/infosys/gidl2/shiplabel/mybatis/config/" + propsDB;
...
InputStream is = getClass( ).getResourceAsStream(ENDINGS_FILE_NAME);
```

But first remember to set resources folder in your `web.xml`, because tomcat needs to know where search it.

Comment: could you also please tell me how to set the resources in `web.xml`. Sorry, this is my first web-app and I kinda confused.

Comment: I made mistake, about configuration for your question you don't need to have that configuration. Please check weather my method works for you and give me feedback about it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to reference the file from the classpath instead. Try

```
in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("om/infosys/gidl2/shiplabel/mybatis/config/nWMS_database.properties");
```

Make sure that the resource-dev directory is considered a source dir so that it gets included in the WEB-INF/classes of your war file.

Comment: I tried this, but since I am using mybatis, I had also defined properties to be used in the config file for mybatis and after the changes you said, mybatis is not able to recognize the properties file.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to

```
new FileInputStream("com.infosys.gidl2.shiplabel.mybatis.config."+ propsDB);
```

Comment: This works from the stand-alone java app, but still does not work from web-app